# systemctl and where programs are installed

Tags: postgresql, mariadb, systemctl

I am on an *amazon linux* instance that is based afaict on *centos* : e.g. I have used

```
 sudo yum install -y mysql
```

and

```
 sudo yum install -y postgresql
```

While these did install without errors I do not understand much about how to use them in this non */etc/init.d* environment.  When running

```
  systemctl | grep sql
```

Nothing shows up. How can these be enabled / manipulate  when I can not even find them..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be more than issue here: first there needs to be more *postgresql* programs installed as shown in this *gist* : 
 https://gist.github.com/dstroot/2920991   Only certain portions of it actually work - as shown here:

```
sudo yum -y install postgresql postgresql-server postgresql-devel postgresql-contrib postgresql-docs
sudo service postgresql initdb
sudo service postgresql start
```

Now things are looking happier!

[image]

I will look into the *mariadb* / *mysql* later but suspect there were a similar situation of requiring additional packages to the *yum install*.